# Jupyterlab error at startup (likely due to corporate proxy): Uncaught exception GET /lab/api/extensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, proxy, jupyter-lab, jupyter-widget

I get some form of a connection error every time I launch Jupyterlab.

I think it's related to the fact that I'm behind a corporate proxy, and the PYPI manager component attempts a connection that gets blocked. I can see that from the attached screenshot where the Discover Extensions section returns an "Error searching for extensions: Error: Unhandled error". I can't install any extensions indeed.

I've already tried to set the proxy by adding a file called `00-startup.py` under `.ipython\profile_default\startup`

```
import sys,os,os.path
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"]="http://my.proxy.address"
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"]="https://my.proxy.address"
```

This seems to work because I can indeed access the internet through e.g., `requests.get`, but probably the proxy isn't set at the right scope.

What else should I try?

```
[E 2024-02-07 10:17:46.456 ServerApp] Uncaught exception GET /lab/api/extensions?query&page=1&per_page=30&refresh=0&1707297466394 (127.0.0.1
)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/lab/api/extensions?query&page=1&per_page=30&refresh=0&1707
297466394', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\extension_manager_handler.py", line 37, in ge
t
        extensions, last_page = await self.manager.list_extensions(query, page, per_page)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py", line 474, in list_extensions
        await self.refresh(query, page, per_page)
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py", line 508, in refresh
        await self._update_extensions_list(query, page, per_page)
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py", line 681, in _update_extension
s_list
        extensions, last_page = await self.list_packages(query, page, per_page)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py", line 257, in list_packages
        matches = await self.__get_all_extensions()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py", line 311, in __get_all_extensions

        self.__all_packages_cache = await self.__throttleRequest(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py", line 210, in __throttleRequest
        data = await current_loop.run_in_executor(None, fn, *args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1122, in __call__
        return self.__send(self.__name, args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1464, in __request
        response = self.__transport.request(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1166, in request
        return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1178, in single_request
        http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1291, in send_request
        self.send_content(connection, request_body)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1321, in send_content
        connection.endheaders(request_body)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1289, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1048, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 986, in send
        self.connect()
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1459, in connect
        super().connect()
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 952, in connect
        self.sock = self._create_connection(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\socket.py", line 827, in create_connection
        for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
[W 2024-02-07 10:17:46.463 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Unhandled error'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\handlers\extension_manager_handler.py", line 37, in ge
t
        extensions, last_page = await self.manager.list_extensions(query, page, per_page)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py", line 474, in list_extensions
        await self.refresh(query, page, per_page)
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py", line 508, in refresh
        await self._update_extensions_list(query, page, per_page)
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\manager.py", line 681, in _update_extension
s_list
        extensions, last_page = await self.list_packages(query, page, per_page)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py", line 257, in list_packages
        matches = await self.__get_all_extensions()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py", line 311, in __get_all_extensions

        self.__all_packages_cache = await self.__throttleRequest(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "c:\users\myuser\environments\python-default\Lib\site-packages\jupyterlab\extensions\pypi.py", line 210, in __throttleRequest
        data = await current_loop.run_in_executor(None, fn, *args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1122, in __call__
        return self.__send(self.__name, args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1464, in __request
        response = self.__transport.request(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1166, in request
        return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1178, in single_request
        http_conn = self.send_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1291, in send_request
        self.send_content(connection, request_body)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1321, in send_content
        connection.endheaders(request_body)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1289, in endheaders
        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1048, in _send_output
        self.send(msg)
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 986, in send
        self.connect()
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 1459, in connect
        super().connect()
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\http\client.py", line 952, in connect
        self.sock = self._create_connection(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\socket.py", line 827, in create_connection
        for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\socket.py", line 962, in getaddrinfo
        for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
[E 2024-02-07 10:17:46.463 ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/lab",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0"
    }
[E 2024-02-07 10:17:46.463 ServerApp] 500 GET /lab/api/extensions?query&page=1&per_page=30&refresh=0&1707297466394 (b16e48e7fefb415ba263f9ab
59b0c47a@127.0.0.1) 69.01ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab
```

[image: UI screenshot]